# Feature doesn't show up on the map

Tags: openlayers-3

I've been trying the new version (3) of Open Layers. I've modified the icon feature example slightly, so it would show a polygon. I've been searching, reading and trying for a couple of hours, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I don't want to use geoJSON, because I want to dynamically add and remove features.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var point1 = ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  var point2 = ol.proj.transform([35.41, 9.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  var point3 = ol.proj.transform([33.41, 11.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  var polyFeat = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([point1, point2, point3])
  });

  var polyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'blue'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      width: 2
    })
  });

  polyFeat.setStyle(polyStyle);

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [polyFeat]
  });

  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });

  var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
      url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.jsonp'
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 3
    })
  });
</script>
```

Why is the polygon not showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two small things to solve your issue:

First, it's recommended to close a polygon, so declare a fourth point with same coordinates as the first.

```
var point4 = ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

Then, your geometry `new ol.geom.Polygon([point1, point2, point3])` should be `new ol.geom.Polygon([[point1, point2, point3, point4]])`

The important fact here is not the point4 addition but to transform your array point to an array of array of points. See [the API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html) that says OpenLayers 3 `ol.geom.Polygon` constructor expects an `Array.<Array.<ol.Coordinate>>` expected.